# How could I query the specific record with comma?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to query the records which the column contain commas.

Table: device_info

```
device_id       label_id_set
----------      -------------
A001            2,6,7,10,15
A002            5
A003            3,4,5
A004            2,9,10,11,12,15
A005            5,6,7
```

1.
select * from device_info where label_id_set contain '5'

```
result: 

device_id       label_id_set
----------      -------------
A002            5
A003            3,4,5
A005            5,6,7
```

2.
select * from device_info where label_id_set contain '2' and contain '10'

```
result:

device_id       label_id_set
----------      -------------
A001            2,6,7,10,15
A004            2,9,10,11,12,15
```

3.
select * from device_info where label_id_set contain '2' and contain '10' and contain '15'

```
result:

device_id       label_id_set
----------      -------------
A001            2,6,7,10,15
A004            2,9,10,11,12,15
```

Comment: Fix your data model, so you are not storing multiple values in a single column.

Comment: Use `FIND_IN_SET`, but, better yet, stop storing CSV in your tables.

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ Server version: 10.3.16-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution

Comment: @GordonLinoff How could i fix it? thx